# How to create a nested LINQ statement containing two joins

Tags: c#, linq

**UPDATE: BOTH QUERIES INVOLVED IN THIS QUESTION ARE CORRECT. THE CAUSE WAS IN MISSING DATA IN THE TEST ENVIRONMENT.**

I have three tables.

1. The **Cost Center Access** table that has a list of *Cost Centers* and *Users* that have access to them.
2. The **Worksheet** table which contains *Cost Centers* and their corresponding *Balancing Units*.
3. The **Balancing Unit** table which contains *Descriptions* for each *Balancing unit*.

My goal is to return a list of balancing units and their descriptions that are specific to each user. In other words, the first part is that I want to check which Cost Centers a user has access to in the Cost Center Access table and use that to filter out the Balancing units based on their association with the Cost centers.

This part is easy enough to accomplish:

```
var bunits = from csa in _costCenterAccessRepo.GetAll()
                         join w in _worksheetRepo.GetAll() on csa.CostCenterID equals w.CostCenterID
                         where csa.EmplID == user.EmployeeID
                         select new { w.BalancingUnitID };
```

The issue I run into is when I add another join that would allow me to get the corresponding Descriptions for each BalancingUnitID above

I tried the following and it did not return any results:

```
    var bunits = from csa in _costCenterAccessRepo.GetAll()
                 join w in _worksheetRepo.GetAll() on csa.CostCenterID equals w.CostCenterID
                 join b in _balancingUnitRepo.GetAll() on w.BalancingUnitID equals b.ID
                 where csa.EmplID == user.EmployeeID
                 select new { w.BalancingUnitID, b.Description };
```

I can confirm that there is data to be returned and the first query gets me the correct Balancing Units, just not with the Descriptions.

How can I rewrite the above statement to accomplish the result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your join for `w` differs between the two queries.

1. `join w in _worksheetRepo.GetAll() on csa.CostCenterID equals w.CostCenterID`
2. `join w in _worksheetRepo.GetAll() on csa.CostCenterValue equals w.CostCenterID`

---

Start with this dummy data:

```
public static class _costCenterAccessRepo
{
    public static List<CostCenterAccess> GetAll() =>
        new List<CostCenterAccess>()
        {
            new CostCenterAccess() { EmplID = 42, CostCenterID = 1 }
        };
}

public class CostCenterAccess
{
    public int EmplID;
    public int CostCenterID;
}

public static class _worksheetRepo
{
    public static List<Worksheet> GetAll() =>
        new List<Worksheet>()
        {
            new Worksheet() { CostCenterID = 1, BalancingUnitID = 2 }
        };
}

public class Worksheet
{
    public int CostCenterID;
    public int BalancingUnitID;
}

public static class _balancingUnitRepo
{
    public static List<BalancingUnit> GetAll() =>
        new List<BalancingUnit>()
        {
            new BalancingUnit() { ID = 2, Description = "Foo" }
        };
}

public class BalancingUnit
{
    public int ID;
    public string Description;
}

public static class user
{
    public static int EmployeeID = 42;
}
```

Then when I run both of your queries they work just fine.

Comment: Good catch, thank you! This has now been corrected and is not the source of the issue.

Comment: I am puzzled as to why this would be the case. I just stepped through the code again and manually inspected the bunits object and it says "Enumeration yielded no results". If I take away the second Join with _balancingUnitRepo, it works and I get correct results.

Comment: @user1179071 - It works fine with my data. I think your data is wrong.

Comment: Thank you. You were exactly correct. In my test envrionment the BalancungUnit table had a limited number of rows and did not have a match to particular BalancingUnit results I was getting from the rest of the query. Your comment prompted me look at the data and see that. Thank you again.

As this question will be of little value to others I will delete it after you see this response.

Comment: @user1179071 - Don't delete - it shows how to debug.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following: maybe try left join.

```
var bunits = from csa in _costCenterAccessRepo.GetAll()
             join w in _worksheetRepo.GetAll() on csa.CostCenterID equals w.CostCenterID into csaw
from jts in csaw.DefaultIFEmpty()
             join b in _balancingUnitRepo.GetAll() on jts.BalancingUnitID equals b.ID
             where csa.EmplID == user.EmployeeID into anotherJoin
from values in anotherJoin.DefaultIfEmpty()
             select new { jts.BalancingUnitID ?? 0, values.Description ?? String.Empty };
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried the code and I am getting compilation errors on `csa.DefaultIfEmpty()`, `into anotherJoin` and `values.Description`.